# Looking for a unique "Conversation ID" in the App Insights for QnA Maker

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights, azure-qna-maker

We're using [QnA Maker](https://www.qnamaker.ai/) attached to an [Azure Bot Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/bot-service/). In the  Knowledge Base (KB), we've added a [Follow up Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation) to every question that says `This did NOT answer my question`:

[image: Knowledge Base > Follow Up Prompt]

Meaning if a bad response was provided, the end-user could indicate so, and the conversation history would look like this:

[image: Example Conversation]

What we're trying to do is replay that conversation history so we can see:

1. The original user prompt
2. The original answer
3. The subsequent followup question / answer

We have [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model) turned on, so we can see both questions as they come through from the logs with the following query:

```
traces
| project timestamp, 
          itemId,
          question = customDimensions.Question,
          answer = customDimensions.Answer
| order by timestamp
```

Which will return these two rows:

[image: App Insights Logs]

However, we're trying to find a unique conversation id or session id that can correlate both of those records.  Notice that the `itemId` is very similar, but not identical:

```
53be8c14-702c-11ea-8c41-11c1c266dc55
53be8c13-702c-11ea-8c41-11c1c266dc55
```

#### Is there a unique key that can be used to join these two events?

One workaround is to just use the first 7 digits of the `itemID` and join based on that partial match like this:

```
traces
| where customDimensions.Question contains "This did NOT answer my question" 
| project itemId,
          SessionID = extract("^[a-z0-9]{7}", 0, itemId),
          timestamp
| join (
    traces
    | extend question = tostring(customDimensions['Question'])
    | extend answer = tostring(customDimensions['Answer'])
    | where message contains "GenerateAnswer" 
        and question  !contains "This did NOT answer my question" 
    | project itemId,
              SessionID = extract("^[a-z0-9]{7}",0,itemId),
              question,
              answer,
              timestamp
) on SessionID 
| project question, answer, SessionID, timestamp //, itemId, itemId1
| order by timestamp desc, SessionID
```

But we're not sure that value will reliably only differ by the 8th digit, so would prefer a less fragile ID

Comment: Are you just trying to examine this via App Insights? It seems Active Learning might work here, though I haven't personally implemented that yet. Then you could handle collecting the feedback and training your KB directly instead of having to review the App Insights reports.

Comment: itemID seems to be a property of QNA framework:https://github.com/garypretty/qnamaker-sync/blob/master/README.md - and you may want to check how your QnAItem(s) are defined. From your example it looks that first part of the UUID is not stable (53be8c14, 53be8c13) - while the remaining ones are stable (702c-11ea-8c41-11c1c266dc55). My guess would be that it is better to use trailing parts of the UUID.

Comment: Have you considered adding [conversation history](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to your bot, then when the "this did not answer my question" button is clicked, send up a [custom telemetry event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to Application Insights with the data that you want. That way you just query the custom telemetry event details. These could use a combination of the user id, channel id, conversation id, and time as the unique key.

Comment: You might also find this [Power BI template](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/solution-accelerators/tutorials/view-analytics/1-intro/) helpful which allows you to drill into details.

Comment: @MattStannett, can you add that info to an answer?  Providing the simplest vehicle toward collecting a Conversation ID if one isn't available in the default AI data is definitely the next step toward a solution

Answer (score -1):

I recently implemented a QnA maker BOT with active learning.

The sample is located [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/48.qnamaker-active-learning-bot)

It is very similar to what you are trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Hey Sash, I don't think this is what the primary concern was which is how to dig through the logs and get a unique conversation ID.  Adding **Active Learning** is peripheral to that concern